# Is it possible to do object initialization in JavaScript similar to C#?

Tags: javascript

More specifically, for a random class with two public properties, in C# you can do something like this :

```
new Point() {
   Y = 0,
   X = 0
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar in JavaScript? I was thinking of something along the line of :

```
{
   prototype : Object.create(Point.prototype),
   X : 0,
   Y : 0
}
```

but I don't think it works as intended. Or a simple copy function :

```
function Create(object, properties) {
    for (p in properties)
        object[p] = properties[p];

    return object;
}
```

so the object initialization would become :

```
Create(new Point(), {X : 0, Y : 0});
```

but there is an extra object creation. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (in terms of functionality)? Javascript is not C#.

Comment: Copying the prototype of Point into a new object, while initializing different properties of that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Point = { /* methods */ };

Object.create(Point, {
    x: { value: 0 },
    y: { value: 0 }
});
```

Of course that's a bit verbose on the default property initialization so I tend to use an [`extend`](https://gist.github.com/1441105) utility.

```
extend(Object.create(Point), {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ES7:

```
class Point {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
}

// {x: 5, y: 10}
const p = {...new Point(),  x: 5, y: 10 };
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WaLLzJ

Comment: This solution shouldn't be used since the Point prototype is lost when using spread operator.

Answer (score 2):

For those who code in TypeScript, here is another way to do it:

Create a base class:

```
export class BaseClass<T> {
    constructor(data?: Partial<T>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

Extend it:

```
import { BaseClass } from './base.model';

export class Child extends BaseClass<Child > {
    Id: string;
    Label: string;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
const child = new Child({
    Id: 1,
    Label: 'My Label'
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please edit your question and explain a bit more what you are doing, i.e. why your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Object literals are probably the closest:

```
var point = {
    X: 0,
    Y: 0
};
```

Comment: But this method does not copy the prototype of Point. That is the dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing general (that meets your requirements) but you could do this:

```
function Point( x, y ) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}

Point.prototype = { ... };

new Point( 1,2 );
```